# Pandas overwriting columns with to_csv

Tags: python, pandas

I have two data frames: Position and Force. I would like to write Position to the first column, Force to the next, and then repeat the process for each iteration (the file path changes each time the function is called). Right now, I have :

```
Position.to_csv("filepath")
Force.to_csv("filepath")
```

Right now, the force dataframe seems to overwrite Position- I end up with a csv file with one column, the latest Force data frame. Is there a way to get to_csv to add a column instead of just write to the first one?

Thanks!

Comment: Why not just take the columns from both and write them out? e.g. `pd.concat([Position, Force], axis=1, ignore_index=True).to_csv("filepath")` This saves the hassle of iterating a row at a time and will be much faster and easier to understand

Comment: @EdChum that works great for getting the two columns I want. However it still only gives me the data from the latest filepath, when I would like to have one csv file with all of the data in the format: position, force, position, force, position, force etc. Any idea?

Comment: So you want just one long row?

Comment: What I'd like to have is data from all the tests in one csv file. Column 1 is the Position data from test 1, column 2 is the Force data from test 1. Column 3 is the position data from test 2, Column 4 is the position data from test 2, etc.

Comment: Just make a list of the columns from the dataframes you want and use concat: `df_list = [test_1['Position'], test_1['Force'], test_2['Position'], test_2['Position']]  pd.concat(df_list, axis=1, ignore_index=True).to_csv("filepath")` if the order is as regular as you say you could easily write a simple for loop to build this list